# Windows Server 2016 Standard Processor Groups

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-server-2016

I'm using vmware and assigned 64 logical processors and 64 sockets. But the operating system is dividing the number of processors into two different uneven processor groups.

From reading Microsoft documentation it stats that I should only have 1 processor group for 64 or less processors.

See Photo below, what will be the cause of this, and how can I force it to be 1 processor group?

[image: Photo of Processor Groups]

Comment: What specific use case do you have where you need 64 vCPU for a Windows server instance?

Comment: I provide resources for people who order them with the specification requested, they pay for it, they get it. I don't get into what they use it for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out in VMWare 75 processors were assigned, but windows only recognized 64 of those processors. Which I guess is a different issue. But when it was changed back down to 64 processors in VMWare, then it turned into 1 CPU Group[image: CPU Group]